# How would you save the contents of a directory to a variable in dart?

Tags: dart, directory

I'm trying to list the contents of a directory in Dart, I at first tried to see if there was a function which would return the names of the files and sub-directorys as an array, like the `os.listdir()` function in python. I couldn't find such a function. However, after some searching I found this code which could print the contents of a directory to the terminal but could not save it to a variable.

```
var filesAndFolders;
var systemTempDir = Directory(".");
systemTempDir.list(recursive: false, followLinks: false)
    .listen((FileSystemEntity entity) {
        print(entity.path);
        filesAndFolders = entity.path;
    });
print(filesAndFolders);
```

while the output of this code is :

```
null
./tmp
./NikScorchSkin.png
./Access Server
./System Cleanup.sh
./Access Server.py
./Access Server.dart
./Access Server.sh
./.mountAccessServer
```

Another problem, although not as important, `null` is representing `filesAndFolders` and yet is printed before the listing of the directory rather than after it. Any reasons for that would be appreciated but are not essential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example does not make much sense and contains multiple problems. Let go though each of them.

**Type problem with `filesAndFolders`**

The variable `filesAndFolders` does not have any specific type or initialized with a value. So Dart does have some problems identifying the type of this variable. It does not help that you are later in your code using this variable and thinking it is some kind of list.

Since we want to save a list of paths we can initialize our list to contain strings like this:

```
final filesAndFolders = <String>[];
```

When adding elements to the list you should then call `add()` like:

```
filesAndFolders.add(entity.path);
```

**Async and sync operations combined**

You are using the `list` operation on a directory which is documented to return `Stream<FileSystemEntity>` which means we will asynchronicity get each `FileSystemEntity` in the directory.

By calling `listen` on a `Stream` you are giving a callback method which will be called at some point when the Dart have received the list of files from the OS. The `listen` call is therefore not synchronously and Dart will just run though the rest of your program.

This is the reason why you are seeing `print(filesAndFolders);` is running before your callback method.

Also, Dart is single threaded and works with a event queue behind the scene. So your callback method you have given `listen` is only going to be executed when there are nothing else there can be executed.

There are two solutions for this:

*The sync. way*

You can use the `listSync` method instead which are returning `List<FileSystemEntity>` which you can go trough in a normal synchronous way:

```
  for (final entity in systemTempDir.listSync(recursive: false, followLinks: false)) {
    print(entity.path);
  }
```

*The async. way*

Dart allows us to mark a method `async` which gives the ability to easily indicate when we want to asynchronously wait for something to happen. We can therefore rewrite your code into:

```
void main() async {
...

  await for (final entity in systemTempDir.list(recursive: false, followLinks: false)) {
    print(entity.path);
  }
}
```

By using `await for` we can easily subscribe to a `Stream` and process each event before we continue the executing of the rest of the method.

The final method will look like this in both sync and async:

**Sync**

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  final filesAndFolders = <String>[];
  final systemTempDir = Directory(".");

  for (final entity in systemTempDir.listSync(recursive: false, followLinks: false)) {
    print(entity.path);
    filesAndFolders.add(entity.path);
  }
  print(filesAndFolders);
}
```

**Async**

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  final filesAndFolders = <String>[];
  final systemTempDir = Directory(".");

  await for (final entity in systemTempDir.list(recursive: false, followLinks: false)) {
    print(entity.path);
    filesAndFolders.add(entity.path);
  }
  print(filesAndFolders);
}
```